# GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers() Not Working in release build after migrating to AndroidX

Tags: android, gson, http-post, httprequest, androidx

Before migrating to **androidX**, the release build is working fine with ***HTTP request***.

After migrating to **androidX**, every **GET** request is working, but all of the **POST** request is not working. It can't send arguments to the server-side. All the content of the **POST** request is empty.

The only change I've done is migrate this project to **androidX**.

Main reason is `GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers()` is not working and return empty json string.

POJO object

```
public class Person {

public static final int MAJOR = 0;
public static final int MINOR = 1;
private String uniqueId;
private String name;
private String nickName;
private String localUniqueId;
protected String tempAdrss;

public String getUniqueId() {
    return uniqueId;
}

public void setUniqueId(String uniqueId) {
    this.uniqueId = uniqueId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getNickName() {
    return nickName;
}

public void setNickName(String nickName) {
    this.nickName = nickName;
}

public String getLocalUniqueId() {
    return localUniqueId;
}

public void setLocalUniqueId(String localUniqueId) {
    this.localUniqueId = localUniqueId;
}

public String getTempAdrss() {
    return tempAdrss;
}

public void setTempAdrss(String tempAdrss) {
    this.tempAdrss = tempAdrss;
}}
```

When we put data and send it to Valley Request `GsonBuilder()` returns an empty object.

```
   Person person=new Person();
   person.setName("Abc");
   pesron.getUniqueId("abcdef");

   Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.PROTECTED, Modifier.PUBLIC).create();
   String requestBody = gson.toJson(person);
```

`requestBody` returns `{}` and when we remove **Modifiers** then it returns jsonString with ***all variables***.

Comment: What do you mean by it's working for `GET` request but not working for `POST` request ?

Comment: @Abhishek `new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.PROTECTED, Modifier.PUBLIC).create();` not working